#  Unknown server tag 'asp:ListView' error with Sharepoint 2010 / .Net 3.5

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, list-view

I'm developing a visual web part in Visual Studio 2010 for sharepoint and i have a listview control embedded.

I keep getting this error message in runtime even though I made sure it's namespaces are included and everything in the right place.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read some threads talking about a bug in .net 3.5 and that we need to reinstall the SP1 to solve the problem, while I found this time-savy solution by simply adding a line to web.config:

inside the tag:

```
<Pages>
<Controls> 
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</Controls>
</Pages>
```

Good luck

Comment: replace start tag with <%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" .... and add it directly in your ascx

Answer (score 2):

Made sure the build setting is 3.5 and not 3.5 Client Profile?

Comment: yeah, it's installed with Sharepoint 2010. so It's not the client profile

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Web Part template references the Extensions DLL that comes in .NET 3.5, but does not register all of the namespaces. This means the namespace `System.Web.UI.WebControls` needed for ListView is missing.

Below this line:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI"
    Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

Add:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"
    Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```